# How to display the strings from a list of strings that contain all the chars from a char array? c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a list of strings and a char array of letters. And I want to display the strings that contain all the chars from the array in the string.

List-list of strings
charsArray-array of chars
Final-the final list with the sorted words

Example

```
charsArray  {'a','e','i','z'}
List {"abcde","iertaz","aio","zzeml","amoioze"}
Final(output)  iertaz amoioze
```

I tried this

```
foreach(string word in List)
{
    bool contain = true;
    foreach (char letter in charsArray}
    {
        if (word.Contains(letter) && contain)
        {
            Final.Add(word);
        }
        else
        {
            contain = false;

        }

    }

}
foreach (string word in Final)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: did you want the words "sorted" in the original order or some other way?

Comment: did you want to check if at least a word in list has all characters in char array ?

Comment: yes exactly ! @Hoshani

Comment: I usually use string.Join("", array) to combine characters into a string.  The join character is an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Having

```
char[] chars = new char[] {
  'a','e','i','z'};

List<string> list = new List<string>() {
  "abcde", "iertaz", "aio", "zzeml", "amoioze" };
```

We can try *subtracting* `word` from `chars`: if all characters from `chars` are removed, the `word` is what we want:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var result = list
  .Where(word => !chars.Except(word).Any())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Extracting a small `ContainsAll` extension method using your logic there might be a good idea to improve semantic value and readability.

Comment: @julealgon: Yes, if such a logic appears in other places, `ContainsAll` (and may be `ContainsAny`, `ContainsAtLeast` etc.) extension methods should be implemented.

Comment: "if such a logic appears in other places" I think there is value to add it even if this is the only usage though. Extracting code is not done solely for reuse reasons in some cases.

Comment: @julealgon: tastes differ; I don't like have a lot of (extensions) methods which I rarely use and which obscure my frequent methods. Often I say "grrr!" when I try to put `Concat` while Intellisence once again suggest `ContainsAll`. I can't see much harm in three lines in a code, it can be extracted; but in case of the only usage I'd rather extract the metod as `private` one within the class where it's used.

Comment: If you were going to make an extension method you'd probably want to make it generic, optimized or both. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73473563/659190

Comment: @Jodrell: yes, when providing an extension method (as you have done) we should make it generic, optimized, readable etc. I like your approach and you get my +1.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `All`:

```
var charsArray = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'z' };
var L = new[] { "abcde","iertaz","aio","zzeml","amoioze"}.ToList();

var final = L.Where(word => charsArray.All(a => word.Contains(a))).ToList();
```

The result is correct:
iertaz
amoioze

Answer (score 1):

How about this, [demonstrated here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BUkQRv)

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ContainsAll<T>(
                                            this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source,
                                            IEnumerable<T> search,
                                            IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(search);
    comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    
    var searchSet = search is HashSet<T> ss && ss.Comparer == comparer
        ? ss
        : new HashSet<T>(search, comparer);

    return source.Where(item => searchSet.IsSubsetOf(item));
}
```

That you can use like this,

```
var words = new[] {"abcde","iertaz","aio","zzeml","amoioze"};
var search = new[] {'a','e','i','z'};
foreach (string match in words.ContainsAll(search))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Comment: Small issues: since you have extracted a method and made it `public`, I suggest input *parameters validation* (`source` and `search` must not be `null`); probably `IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default` declaration is slightly *more readable* than current `comparer = null`. May be you want to optimize a bit: `var searchSet = search is HashSet<T> ss && ss.Comparer == comparer ? ss : new HashSet<T>(search, comparer);` in case `search` is already a required HashSet. All the other is nice and clear, my +1

Comment: Side note: Linq alternative is `return source.Where(item => searchSet.IsSubsetOf(item));`

Answer (score 0):

In this line you are adding the word if the first character is in the word because contain is true

```
...
if (word.Contains(letter) && contain)
        {
            Final.Add(word);
        }
...
```

you are almost there, you just need a little modification to avoid the mistake above

```
foreach(string word in List)
{
    bool contain = true;
    foreach (char letter in charsArray}
    {
        if (!word.Contains(letter))
        {
            contain = false;
        }
    }

  if (contain) 
  {
    Final.Add(word);
  }

}
foreach (string word in Final)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to find strings that contain all the chars from `charsArray`. It means every char in `charsArray` should be contained by the target string.

```cs
using System.Linq;

var List = new List<string>() { "abcde", "iertaz", "aio", "zzeml", "amoioze" };
var charsArray = new char[] { 'a','e','i','z' };
var result = List.FindAll(word => charsArray.All(letter => word.Contains(letter)));
```